# How can i get this code executed instead of having it appear on the browser? Please assist

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware, laravel-facade

```
@if(\Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->uri() == 'dashboard' || \Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->uri() == 'welcome' || \Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->uri() == 'change-password' ||
        \Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->uri() == 'not-found' )@endif
```

Comment: Add `<?` at start of the page

Comment: it is a blade.php file

Answer (score 0):

In case of PHP, add `<?php` at the beggining of the file and `?>` at the end of the file.

Other than PHP, search online.